# Splitting authors between two tiers

Tags: formatting

I am preparing a tex file that has four authors. Of the four, two have made a substantial novel intellectual contribution to the document, while the other two have just helped to draft it.

They should all be credited as authors of the document, but what I would ideally like is to have two authors (with footnote affiliations), followed by some text along the lines of "with assistance in documentation from", in turn followed by the other authors' names.

At the moment I am using `\maketitle` and would like something like

Author One and Author Two

With assistance in documentation from

Author Three and Author Four

And then the abstract, etc.

I can't see any way of using `\author` to split the authors into multiple sections with text intervening.

```
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% Insert author blurb here

\title{title}
\begin{abstract}abstract\end{abstract}
\maketitle
body
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, there are probably several ways. You have to be more specific and provide a minimal example. For instance, do you want to use `\maketitle` or are you typesetting your title by hand? How is the layout of your title, and which part exactly of what you want to do, do you have problems with?

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean to prepare a minimum example of something that I find myself unable to do. I'll edit some more information in the question, though.

Comment: Very easy, a working example can be compiled. It shows your `\documentclass`, contains all necessary packages, contains `\begin{document}...end{document}` and everything you have as a starting point and to demonstrate the error in between. Without those information, it will be hard to help you, because answers will depend on your document-setup.

Comment: @manuelweinkauf is this helpful?

Comment: Yes, but it shows that what you want may be a bit difficult. You use `\documentclass{revtex4-1}`, which has strict design rules. So it is probably not an option to create your own `\titlepage`. Have you looked at the `\thanks{}` [command](https://d22izw7byeupn1.cloudfront.net/files/revtex/auguide4-1.pdf) for authors. It will probably not produce what you want, but may allow you to specify the two authors as "assistants" via a footnote, which is probably the way it should be done in this style anyways.

Comment: I could probably use a different article class. The issue with the `\thanks` command for me is that it links the thanks to a specific one of the authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The revtex class offers the possibility of specifying a `\collaboration` which can be mis-/re-used for your purpose; one just has to get rid of the parentheses, which are added automatically by revtex (but which can be used to inject extra space before and after the collaboration text).

The code below results in the following output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{xpatch} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter       % <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\xpatchcmd\@collaboration@present{(}{\medskip}{}{} % <<<<< opening par is replaced by some space before
\xpatchcmd\@collaboration@present{)}{}{}{} % <<<<< closing par is removed
\makeatother % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}
\author{Bugs Bunny}
\affiliation{Looney Tune Studios}
\author{Roger Rabbit}
\affiliation{Looney Tune Studios}
\affiliation{Disney World}
\collaboration{with assistance in documentation from}
\noaffiliation
\author{Mickey Mouse}
\affiliation{Disney World}
\author{Minnie Mouse}
\affiliation{Disney World}
\title{title}
\begin{abstract}abstract\end{abstract}
\maketitle
body
\end{document}
```